# Does firestore have a json url to show data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

with firebase I use these urls a lot to quickly view my data in the browser:
- https://YOUR_DB.firebaseio.com/YOUR_COLLECTION.json
- https://YOUR_DB.firebaseio.com/YOUR_COLLECTION/YOUR_DOCUMENT.json

It gives a json representation of the data for that particular collection or document.

Is there an equivalent in Firestore?

Comment: doesnt seem to have

Answer (score 2):

Those URLs are the [REST API of the Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).

While there is a [REST API for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/) it works *very* differently.

Comment: Use Google API Explorer to build the url you need https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1/